# MODIS Projection Google Earth Engine

Tags: coordinate-system, modis, google-earth-engine, modis-reprojection-tool

Why if I applied a code over a MODIS collection and then I download an image, the image is in WGS projection? The code is the next:

```js
// Simple regression of year versus NDVI.

// Define the start date and position to get images covering TDPS,
// Bolivia, from 2000-2010.
var start = '2000-01-01';
var end = '2008-12-31';

var region = table3


// Filter to Collection
// time of year to avoid seasonal affects, and for each image create the bands
// we will regress on:
// 1. A 1, so the resulting array has a column of ones to capture the offset.
// 2. Fractional year past 2000-01-01.
// 3. SAVI.
// 4. Mask Clouds
var col = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/MOD13Q1")
  .filterDate(start, end)
  .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(1,1,'month'))
  .filterBounds(region)
  .map(function(image) {
    var date = ee.Date(image.get('system:time_start'));
    var yearOffset = date.difference(ee.Date(start), 'year');
    var savi = image.expression(
      '(1 + L) * float(nir - red)/ (nir + red + L)',
      {
        'nir': image.select('sur_refl_b02'),
        'red': image.select('sur_refl_b01'),
        'L': 0.5
      });
    return ee.Image(1).addBands(yearOffset).addBands(savi).toDouble();
  });

print(col)
// Convert to an array. Give the axes names for more readable code.
var array = col.toArray();
var imageAxis = 0;
var bandAxis = 1;

// Slice off the year and savi, and solve for the coefficients.
var x = array.arraySlice(bandAxis, 0, 2);
var y = array.arraySlice(bandAxis, 2);
var fit = x.matrixSolve(y).clip(region);

// Get the coefficient for the year, effectively the slope of the long-term
// SAVI trend.
var slope = fit.arrayGet([1, 0]).clip(region);

Map.addLayer(slope);

// Export the image, specifying scale and region.
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: slope,
  description: 'SAVI_slope_jan_MODIS_00_08',
  scale: 250,
  maxPixels: 1e9,
  region: geometry
});
```

But if I download an image from that collection it is in MODIS SINUSOIDAL. The code is the next:

```js
//Choose country using GEE Feature Collection
var region = table;

var collection = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/MOD13Q1')
.filterDate('2000-01-01', '2014-12-31')
.filterBounds(region)
.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(1,1,'month'));

print(collection)

// Collect data and filter by total dates
var modis_savi = ee.Image('MODIS/MOD13Q1/MOD13Q1_005_2001_01_01');

print(modis_savi)


var savi = modis_savi.expression(
      '(1 + L) * float(nir - red)/ (nir + red + L)',
      {
        'nir': modis_savi.select('sur_refl_b02'),
        'red': modis_savi.select('sur_refl_b01'),
        'L': 0.5
      });



Map.addLayer(savi.clip(region))


// Export the image, specifying scale and region.
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: savi,
  description: 'MODIS_JAN_1_2001',
  scale: 250,
  maxPixels: 1e9,
  region: table
});
```

Does anyone know why?

Comment: Probably because the conversion to/from array caused a reprojection. Why is the exported CRS an issue anyway? If you want to export it in a different projection you could always use the `crs` parameter to set one.

Comment: Quoting from https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/exporting _If not explicitly specified, the CRS of the output will be taken from the first band of the image to be exported. You may also specify the dimensions, crs and/or crs_transform of the exported image. See the glossary for more information on crs and crs_transform. For example, to get a block of pixels precisely aligned to another data source, specify dimensions, crs and crs_transform_. That is for consistency you need to specify the crs parameter, e.g. `'crs':'EPSG:4326'`